# undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

I'm following [Qt's guide](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QPushButton) for using a `QPushButton`.

I did exactly as the guide suggests, but I'm getting a compilation error:

```
./src/mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
./src/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x25): more undefined references to `vtable for MainWindow' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloWorldProj] Error 1
```

I tried adding a destructor:

```
~MainWindow(){};
```

but the problem persisted.

I have no virtual functions declared, except one function inside `QMainWindow` (the class I'm inheriting from):

```
virtual QMenu *createPopupMenu();
```

Should this be defined in my class?

Comment: Add `Q_OBJECT` to your class declaration, run qmake and build again.

Comment: I have a `Q_OBJECT`: `class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
 Q_OBJECT...}`

Comment: Improve your question.

Comment: My exact code is like the linked website. There's nothing I can add to my question...

Comment: @AlaaM. See my updated answer

Comment: I have updated the example on the website to include the pro file needed for the example to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running qmake on the project and then do a rebuild.

Your example is broken (I will update it shortly if possible)

Create an empty file and name it PushButtonExample.pro and add the following:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = PushButtonExample
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

Then run `qmake` on that file, then `make`.

I also recommend that you download Qt Creator and use that as your IDE when building Qt project. Most Qt installs also install the Qt Creator IDE  and it has some nice examples and wizards to create new projects.

Make sure all 4 files are in the same folder

```
main.cpp
mainwindow.cpp
mainwindow.h
PushButtonExample.pro
```

In command line, navigate into that folder and run qmake

```
qmake PushButtonExample.pro
```

This should create the following file in the same folder

```
Makefile
```

Then run `make`

This should build the example, and finally run the application:

```
./PushButtonExample
```

(I am also updating the wiki page)

Comment: I  tried `qmake HelloWorldProj` (that's the name of the project), but I'm getting `Cannot find file: HelloWorldProj.`

Comment: `qmake HelloWorldProj.pro`

Comment: you need a *.pro file and then run qmake on that, if you do not have  a *.pro file then there are other issues. See comment of @KernelPanic

Comment: Now getting `Cannot find file: HelloWorldProj.pro.`

Comment: I can't find `HelloWorldProj.pro`. Only the `HelloWorldProj` folder, and inside it there's **Debug** , **Release** , **src**. In **Debug** and **Release** there's makefiles

Comment: For qmake you need a .pro file. What is the command that you used to build the code to get the above error?

Comment: **Build All** from eclipse (or by creating a new Make Target). Both ways run `make all`

Comment: OK I ran `qmake PushButtonExample.pro` but I get `Cannot find file: PushButtonExample.pro.` although it's there. Also tried `./PushButtonExample.pro`. Same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94724/discussion-between-the-badger-and-alaa-m).

Comment: To add to this answer, to make it work from eclipse this needs to be done: In **Make Target** view, make new target: **Name:** qmake , **Make Target**: **FULL PATH** to .pro file , **Build Command:** qmake. Finally, run this target and then Build All.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` to `ON` in our CMake file.

```
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

"The AUTOMOC target property controls whether cmake inspects the C++ files in the target to determine if they require moc to be run, and to create rules to execute moc at the appropriate time." - [Reference](https://wiki.qt.io/Using_CMake_build_system)