# A missing vtable while implementing MainWindow in main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

The Qt projects on QtCreator usually keep main.cpp separated from QtMainWindow derived classes.

I tried to move it to main.cpp but got stuck:

myapp.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent=0) : QMainWindow(parent) { }
    virtual ~MainWindow() override {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Then and got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for MainWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [demo1.app/Contents/MacOS/demo1] Error 1
```

Having a difficult time trying to find the mistake I made. Any comments?

Comment: maybe this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633056/undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-mainwindow

Comment: I tried make distclean, also rm all other files and qmake then make.. still the same error

Comment: @KcFnMi add `#include "main.moc"` at the end of the file

Comment: You mean, `#include "main.moc"` at the en of `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `moc` problem.  When subclassing a QObject that uses the `Q_OBJECT` macro, you need to put it in its own file.  You can't compile it with your `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

The meta-object compiler (moc) only processes header files (.h). The [moc documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html) mentions this briefly. I'm guessing it's because the declaration of a QObject subclass alone is sufficient to generate the signals/slots code; i.e. the implementation that would normally be in the .cpp file is unnecessary for moc to do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is because you did not declare the destructor:

```
virtual ~MainWindow() override {}
```

That's the one function that will trigger the compiler code necessary to create the vtable.

Comment: Good to know. Altought still having the same error.

Comment: It may be a `moc` problem, which would add a class you have to derive from to complete the `Q_OBJECT`.